# Omit hash from output filename when building with "cargo rustc -- -o filename" possible?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to control output filename with cargo? `cargo rustc -- -o filename` gives *filename-hash*:

```
$ mkdir output-filename
$ cd output-filename/
$ cargo init
    Created binary (application) package
$ cargo rustc -v --release -- -o filename
  Compiling output-filename v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/output-filename)
    Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name output_filename src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -o filename -C metadata=c961d75f8bcf3c48 -C extra-filename=-c961d75f8bcf3c48 --out-dir /private/tmp/output-filename/target/release/deps -L dependency=/private/tmp/output-filename/target/release/deps`
warning: due to multiple output types requested, the explicitly specified output file name will be adapted for each output type

warning: ignoring --out-dir flag due to -o flag

warning: ignoring -C extra-filename flag due to -o flag

    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.39s
$ ls
Cargo.lock          filename-c961d75f8bcf3c48   src
Cargo.toml          filename-c961d75f8bcf3c48.d target
```

The output even suggest that `-C extra-filename=-c961d75f8bcf3c48` is ignored, but does not seem to be the case. I can script this, for example

```
mv $(ls filename* | grep -E 'filename-\w+$') filename
```

but I rather find out how to control cargo / rustc.

Comment: This may be a bug, see cargo issue 6899: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6899

Comment: 4 years later - and I would have loved to see an answer for this very question... (: